# Flash AIR input text clears value after IOS keyboard is dismissed

Tags: ios, actionscript-3, flash, air

I have an AIR for IOS app that has some text input fields. The UI is created in Flash Pro and export a swc file for the AIR / Flex app to use.

On IOS If I select the input field the IOS keyboard launches just fine but then when I dismiss the keyboard any text that I enter is cleared from that input field.

Comment: Same behavior if you compile in Flash Pro?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this is a `TextInput`, set the `skinClass` style to `spark.skins.mobile.TextInputSkin`. This has been an issue with that component since Flex 4.6 and is fixed by using the mobile skin.

Comment: the problem I'm having is with fl.controls.TextInput ... The view is built in Flash Pro and then used in the Flex/AIR app.  Any thoughts on fixing that ?

Comment: Unfortunately, no. I was referring to `spark.components.TextInput`, the Flex component. I have no experience with that control. Look for an option for using `StageText` or turning off `TLF` text.